# Split torch tensor dimension on two

Tags: pytorch, tensor

If I have a torch tensor of shape [2, 12] is it possible to make from it a tensor of shape [3, 2, 4] in such a way that data will be split on chunks along the last dimension? View function does not change the order of data, but here I need change the order, that the new dimension will be the first, and the second dimension would not be changed

Here is example image of how data must be split

```
[2, 12]  
............   
............  
   
[3, 2, 4]  
....|....|....   
....|....|....
```

torch.split function does exactly what I need in sense of shape, but it outputs not a tensor, but a tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to split the 12 sized dimension into the leading 3 and trailing 4 dimensions. You simply need to view and [permute](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html) dimensions:

```py
X = torch.permute(X.view(2, 3, 4), (1, 0, 2))
```

Comment: I'd rather chain it as `X.view(-1, 3, 4).transpose(0,1)` :)

Comment: It's magic! I didn't suspect, that permute can do it :) Thank you very much!